# Caddy return empty headers although setted in golang server

Tags: go, https, caddy

I am using caddy to enable https:
I have to add header_down to add these headers.
Without this, the browser will receive empty headers.

```
https://dev.bee.com:3002 {
    encode gzip
    tls cert/server.crt cert/server.key
#    log {
#       output stdout
#    }
    reverse_proxy /* dev.bee.com:3001 {
        header_down Access-Control-Allow-Origin "http://dev.bee.com:3000,http://localhost:3000"
        header_down Access-Control-Allow-Credentials "true"
        header_down Access-Control-Allow-Headers "Origin,Content-Length,Content-Type"
    }
}
```

Comment: What is your question?

Comment: Why canot it forward server header to browser？

Comment: why do you have different ports? 3000/3001/3002. Can you describe your setup more?